# Pause and Resume the execution in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Is there any way to pause and resume the execution in WPF App [especially in ViewModel class]?
I have tried with Auto and ManualResetEvent class. But it is not pausing at the point where I want to pause. The waitone method is not pausing the execution.

In my viewmodel, i have a method which calls the web service. The result of the web service will be coming in another method [ie, the call back method]. After getting the result from the web service, i want to continue the execution.

```
public void Method1()
{
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
      // Call the web service. No waiting for the result.
      // Block the execution here....
   }
}

public void CallBackMethod(int serviceResult)
{
   // After getting the result...
   // I want to continue with Method1...
}
```

Is there any way to do it in WPF ?

Comment: So you have asynchronous calls and you whant to make them synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
private ManualResetEvent _reset;

public void Method1()
{  
   _reset = new ManualResetEvent(true);
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
       // Call the web service.

       // WaitOne blocks the current thread 
       _reset.WaitOne();
   }
}

public void CallBackMethod(int serviceResult)
{
   // After getting the result...

   // Set allows waiting threads to continue
   _reset.Set();
}
```

Comment: No.  ManualResetEvents need to be constructed in the UNSIGNALED state!  Constructing it as signalled is the op's original problem :)

Comment: @GarryVass I don't think so ... he wants to execute each service call, wait, then proceed.  So initially signalled, then each time `WaitOne` to block.

Comment: @dbaseman Thanks for the help. But the WPF UI is non responsive !!! Any way to solve it ???

Answer (score 0):

But why do you need to do this in a loop? Simply run the service again when the callback method is called:

```
int count =0;
const int MAX_CALLS = 5;

public void RunService()
{
    //do service stuff
}

public void CallBackMethod(int serviceResult)
{
    if (count++ < MAX_CALLS)
        RunService ();
}
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    RunService ();
}
```

Comment: @SteveHouben hi friend, i am not calling the RunService method again. In the for loop, i am need to do runservice for each looping.